# Value of a Forward contract at an intermediate time

Tags: contracts

Suppose we hold a forward contract on a stock with expiration 6 months from now. We entered into this contract 6 months ago so that when we entered into the contract, the expiration was T=1 year. 
The stock price$ 6 months ago was S0=100, the current stock price is 125 and the current interest rate is r=10% compounded semi-annually. (This is the same rate that prevailed 6 months ago.) What is the current value of our forward contract?

Comment: If you want help with "homework" problems, I'd suggest showing what you know to do so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: So, I'm using the formula = (S0-current stock price)e^(-10%*6/12) to calculate the value but then I find that the other things doesn't come into the picture.

Comment: Is it that I should first calculate the forward price for the 6 months period and then using that price calculate the forward contract.

Comment: Can anyone please let me know what is the issue with this question? I'm not getting any response for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is incorrect.

The fair future value of a stock (with interest compounding semi-anually) is

```
 F = S * (1+r/2)^(2t)
```

The fair future value when you purchased the forward was:

```
100 * (1+0.05)^2 = 110.25
```

The current fair value of the forward that expires in 6 months is

```
125 * (1+0.05)^1 = 131.25
```

So the current value of the forward is

```
131.25 - 110.25 = 21
```

Comment: I think to calculate the current value of forward we must multiply the answer obtained with the discount factor, i.e 21/(1+0.1/2) which gives 20 as the answer and not 21.

Comment: @HarshitPandey No, the "current" forward value is already at the present time, so there's no need to discount it. You entered a contract to buy at 110.25, and the current forward price is 131.25, so you have a paper profit of 21.

Comment: @DStanley I get the same result as Harshit using another forward property : as r is constant, f_t = S_t - S_0(1+r/n)^nt = 20 in this case

Comment: @HarshitPandey I'm supposing you're taking the Fin Engineer Coursera track, you can find the algebra of that way of calculating f_t (with constant rate) in the Week2 Forum (1st post).